# Deserializing Json getting error "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array"

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am Deserializing Json with below code.

```
public class MyArray
        {
            public int RequestID { get; set; }
            public int Status { get; set; }
            public string ResponseMessage { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class Root
        {
            public List<MyArray> MyArray { get; set; }
        }
   var rawJson = "[{\"RequestID\":12345,\"Status\":100,\"ResponseMessage\": \"API Call Successful\"}]";

 var myDeserializedClass1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(rawJson);
```

I am getting below error. It is not populating the the My Array.
Any thoughts on what's going wrong here.

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'xyz.Root' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
```

Comment: Raw json is simply one element... not an array. Deserialize to MyArray, not List of MyArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update Based on change in OP**

As per your latest edit in the question, you have an array of `MyArray`. You should hence deserialize using a collection of MyArray.

For example,

```
 var myDeserializedClass1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyArray[]>(rawJson); 
// OR
 var myDeserializedClass1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<MyArray>>(rawJson);
```

**Based on Original Question before the Edit**

You are attempting to deserialize using wrong object type (`Root`), which is why it fails to do so, and returns a null value.

Your Json contains a single instance of `MyArray` and not an instance of `Root`. You need to deserialize using

```
var myDeserializedClass1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyArray>(rawJson);
```

That would provide you the desired result.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is working this way. Please recheck the question, i have done some edits.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON simply doesn't contain an Array. A JSON array typically starts with a `[` and ends with a `]`.

So either you change your JSON to this:

```json
[
  {
    "RequestID": 12345,
    "Status": 100,
    "ResponseMessage": "API Call Successful"
  }
]
```

Or try and deserialize to the MyArray object immediately like so:

```cs
var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyArray>(json);
```

Comment: `[]` This was there previously, i removed it. I have edited question now. please check.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to make it deserializable to `Root` object, 'rawJson' should be something like this:

```
var rawJson = "{\"MyArray\":[{\"RequestID\":12345,\"Status\":100,\"ResponseMessage\": \"API Call Successful\"}]}";
```

By the way, if your `Root` class does not have any other data or behavior, you can simply desrialize a `List` of `MyArray`:

```
var rawJson = "[{\"RequestID\":12345,\"Status\":100,\"ResponseMessage\": \"API Call Successful\"}]";
 var myDeserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyArray>>(rawJson);
```

In the code above, `myDeserializedObject` is of type List. You can also deserialize this to any collection like `MyArray[]`, `IList<MyArray>` or enumerable `IEnumerable<MyArray>`.

take a look at the live code in this [dot net fiddle file](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jdkJMK) I created.